# Error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test@admin.co"

Tags: android, error-handling, numberformatexception

How Can I Solve This Error?

Here is My Data Class

```
data class SsnRequest(
private val ssn: String,
private val customer_id: Int,
```

)

And This is APIService

```
@POST(AppConstants.PRODUCT_BY_SSN)
suspend fun getSimBySSN(
    @Path("id") salesManagerId: Int,
    @Body ssn: SsnRequest
): Response<SSNResponse>
```

Comment: can you send a sample of the json ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you passing string!

check your data passing to data class

or change your data class like below :

```
data class SsnRequest(
private val ssn: String,
private val customer_id: String,
```